# Nothing happens after selecting the version of Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, entity-framework

Trying to use MySql with Entity Framework.Successfully tested with server explorer the db works.

But when i try to use entity framework with mysql nothing happens. Literally NOTHING! No prompts or errors. The ADO.NET EF wizard reaches until EF version selector and then when i click next > there is no scaffolding or error shown by the EF Wiz.

[This where it goes blank or in short no edmx generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkKn8.png)

I have referenced all of the dlls required from .NET SQL Connector folder

- MySql.Data
- MySql.Data.EntityFramework
- MySql.Web

Versions of MySql and its tools installed -
MySQL Server 5.1
MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.8
MySQL Connector Net 8.0.13

Using VS 2017

Comment: Ive the same problem. Is there already someone who got a workaround for this?

Comment: Any update on this?..